# How do I change copyright owner name in ACM template using overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, acm

I am getting a copyright like this in pdf. I want to change it but am unable to.

©2019 Association for Computing Machinery. Please find the code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\acmConference{blah1}{month year 2020}{placename}
\copyrightyear{2020}




\begin{document}


\title{paper title}
\subtitle{}
\author{\textbf{Author 1, Author 2}}


\begin{abstract}


\end{abstract}

\begin{CCSXML}
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc{CCs Desc 1}

\keywords{blah blah blah}



\maketitle
\section{INTRODUCTION}


Content goes here.


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hm, are you sure you are allowed to do that? There is a reason for this copyright, I guess ...

Comment: I am using a template provided by a conference. I am sure we can change it as it for different conferences we have different copyrights.

Answer (score 3):

The current list of copyright options provided by [`acmart`](//ctan.org/pkg/acmart) are listed in Table 3 - Parameters of the `\setcopyright` command:

[image]

If you want to print something different, you'll have to perform an explicit change to `\@copyrightowner` using `\renewcommand`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\settopmatter{printacmref=false}

\acmConference{blah1}{month year 2020}{placename}
\copyrightyear{2020}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@copyrightowner}{Something special}
\makeatother

\title{Paper title}
\subtitle{}
\author{Author 1, Author 2}

\begin{abstract}
An abstract
\end{abstract}

\ccsdesc{CCs Desc 1}

\keywords{blah blah blah}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}

Content goes here.

\end{document}
```